# Record audio and play it at the same time

Tags: java, android, media-player

I wouldlike to know if it is possible to record voice from the microphone of my phone and to play it at the same time ?

```
  private void ditchMediaplayer(){
      if (mediaRecorder!=null)mediaRecorder.release();
      try
      {
         mediaPlayer.release();
      }catch (Exception e)
      {
          e.printStackTrace();
      }
  }

      private void beginRecording()throws IOException
      {
          ditchMediaplayer();

          if (outFile.exists())
          {
              outFile.delete();
          }
          mediaRecorder=new MediaRecorder();
          mediaRecorder.setAudioSource(MediaRecorder.AudioSource.MIC);
          mediaRecorder.setOutputFormat(MediaRecorder.OutputFormat.THREE_GPP);
          mediaRecorder.setAudioEncoder(MediaRecorder.AudioEncoder.AMR_NB);
          mediaRecorder.setOutputFile(OUTPUT_FILE);
          mediaRecorder.prepare();
          mediaRecorder.start();
      }

      private void stopRecording()
      {
         if (mediaRecorder !=null)
         {
              mediaRecorder.stop();
         }
      }
```

So I need to use `mediaplayer.play();` ? but I don't know where i can put that for working.

my goal is to stream my voice, but I don't want to record my voice then to play it. I want my voice is recording and playing at the same time.

Thanks for any help !

Comment: You have to finish recording to play it from what i know. You should use a streamer for your purpose i believe

Answer (score 1):

**Recording to an audio file (simple version)**

**Purpose.** Records audio data and stores it in a file. The data is recorded in CD quality (44.1 kHz, 16 bit linear, stereo) and stored in a .wav file.

**Usage.**

```
java SimpleAudioRecorder -h

java SimpleAudioRecorder audiofile
```

**Parameters.**

```
-h
```

print usage information, then exit

```
audiofile
```

the file name of the audio file that should be produced from the recorded data

**Bugs, limitations.**  You cannot select audio formats and the audio file type on the command line. See AudioRecorder for a version that has more advanced options. Due to a bug in the Sun jdk1.3/1.4, this program does not work with it.

**Source code.**  http://www.jsresources.org/examples/SimpleAudioRecorder.java.html

***You should read this it might help***- http://www.jsresources.org/examples/audio_playing_recording.html

Comment: maybe the section "Recording and playing back the recorded data immediately" will help me thx a lot !